# .htaccess rewrite URL with a question mark “?” and extract value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have looked through all the htaccess rewrite URL with a question mark but haven't come across this scenario.

I started with needing this:

```
www.example.com/supplier/company_123.html
```

and rewrite it to:

```
www.example.com/profile.html?id=123
```

This rewrite works:

```
RewriteRule ^supplier/[A-Za-z0-9-]+_([0-9]+)\.html?$ profile.html?id=$1 [NC]
```

However now I want to add a parameter to the original URL:

```
www.example.com/supplier/company_123.html?page=2
```

and change it to

```
www.example.com/profile.html?id=123&page=2
```

I change the htaccess rewrite to

```
RewriteRule ^supplier/[A-Za-z0-9-]+_([0-9]+)\.html?$ profile.html?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^supplier/[A-Za-z0-9-]+_([0-9]+)\.html?$ profile.html?id=$1&page=%1 [NC]
```

But it is not working.  What am I doing wrong?